# Geographical Mapping with SQL and OOP

Tags: gis, geocoding

We are in the development stage of a project that will require mapping unit record data to geographic locations and displaying them on a map  Requirements of the project include the ability to bundle unit records visually (like a heat map) and show layers that include not only known geographic boundaries such as States and Counties, but also custom-defined polygons created by either the programmer or end-user.

While we can create this all from the ground up, over a standard Google Map for example.. I am wondering if this facility already exists in some mapping architecture and if someone can provide valuable references if this is the case.

Comment: Your question really belongs over at http://gis.stackexchange.com/ where you will get better answers from follks who work in the GIS field.

Comment: Thank you I had no idea that site existed.

Comment: np.  Also, I should have added look into PostGIS and OpenLayers over at GIS.SE.  There are lots of questions on those 2 apps that might lead you in the direction you want to go.